# how to use object detection for bank cheque detail extraction?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, google-cloud-automl, automl

I'm working on the project where I need to extract details (cheque no, MICR, branch, a/c no, IFSC) from bank cheques. I decided to use Google AutoML vision object detection for this task but I have the following questions.

1. How to prepare data for training? (which data augmentation techniques to use)
2. How many images I would require to get high accuracy?

[image]

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? I am trying something similar

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, I will try: (No data required)

**Note**: You have to train model to classify if its real cheque or not then run below steps.

```
1. Extract all the text from cheque using [Google Vision OCR API][1]
2. And from all the text array:
         - 6 digit number will be **Cheque Number**
         - 9 digit number will be **MICR code**
         - 10+ digit number will be **Account Number**
         - Text which has branch as text will be **branch name**
         - Text which has bank as text will be **bank name**
         - For IFSC code, you need to compare few initial characters of bank name or do cosine comparison with bank name (run experiment to get more clarity).
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but the end goal is that solution should work offline including text detection and recognition. Idea is to use AutoML vision for training model for edge devices and run inference offline.

Comment: I understand, if you're building Mobile app then Google vision OCR Api can be used offline. I'm not sure, how will you achieve this using AutoML. I encourage you to post solution if you find any. Thanks